# creating custom_id using the concatenation of three columns

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have a table named Products having following columns:

```
create table Products
(ProductId int primary key identity(1,1),
 GroupId int foreign key  references ProductGroup(GroupId),
 SubGroupId int foreign key references ProductSubGroup(SubGroupId),
 Productcode as (GroupId + SubGroupId + ProductId),
 ProductName nvarchar(50) not null unique,
 ProductShortForm nvarchar(5) not null unique,
 PiecesInCarton int not null,
 WeightPerPiece decimal(4,2) not null,
 PurchasePricePerCarton decimal(18,2) not null,
 SalePricePerCarton_CatC decimal(18,2) not null,
 SalePricePerCarton_CatB decimal(18,2) not null,
 SalePricePerCarton_CatA decimal(18,2)
)
```

if GroupId = 34,   SubGroupId = 22  and auto generated ProductId = 12
then ProductCode should be like 34-22-12

how do i do this?

Comment: You need to format the sql in your question.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What is the issue with the code you are using?

Comment: What database engine are you using? The syntax may be different

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you would simply do:

```
Productcode as (concat(GroupId, '-', SubGroupId, '-', ProductId)),
```

The issue with your code is that `+` is interpreted as addition, rather than string concatenation.

In more recent versions, you can use `concat_ws()`:

```
Productcode as (concat_ws('-', GroupId, SubGroupId, ProductId)),
```

> [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) allows you to specify a separator once to inject in between the instances that are being concatenated.
>
> Also note that the inputs are implicitly converted to *char* types when you use `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` so this syntax is simpler than other inline value concatenation methods.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for a view from your table.

```
create view Products_View
 as
select ProductId ,
       GroupId,
       SubGroupId,
       Productcode as (GroupId + SubGroupId + ProductId) as ProductCode,
       ProductName,
       ProductShortForm,
       PiecesInCarton,
       WeightPerPiece,
       PurchasePricePerCarton,
       SalePricePerCarton_CatC,
       SalePricePerCarton_CatB,
       SalePricePerCarton_CatA
   from products
```

Comment: Why does this have to be a view, OP is defining ProductCode as a _non-persisted_ Computed Column in the table itself.

Comment: It can be a computed column, when the post was created there was no tag on the database whether its sql-server or oracle or mysql.

Comment: There still isn't :)